# Why can't Nsolve find the solutions for my equations?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerics, vector

I have a problem using `NSolve` in my Mathematica code. In my Code `NSolve` should find a value for **qw**, but it won't.
The strange thing about this is, that NSolve isn't producing any errors. The first error appears when I try to replace the variables with the Result of `NSolve`

Sorry for the poor effort on the first try, here is the SSEC:

```
BearLM = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 10^7, 1, 0, 0}, {-500,
     0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
RollLM[q_] = {{1, 20, Power[20, 2]/(2* 4.2*10^13), Power[20, 3]/(
    6 *4.2*10^13), q Power[20, 4]/(24* 4.2*10^13)}, {0, 1, 20/( 
    4.2*10^13), Power[20, 2]/(2* 4.2*10^13), 
    q Power[20, 3]/(6 *4.2*10^13)}, {0, 0, 1, 20, 
    q Power[20, 2]/2}, {0, 0, 0, 1, q 20}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}} ;
Vec11 = {vA, phiA, 0, 0, 1};
Vec12 = BearLM. Vec11; 
VecList1 = {Vec12};
Vec21 = {vS, phiS, 0, 0, 1};
Vec22 = BearLM.Vec21;
VecList2 = {Vec22};
Gls := {
   {vAR, phiAR, FQAR, MbAR, 1} == RollLM[qW + 1].Last[VecList1], 
   {vSR, phiSR, FQSR, MbSR, 1} == RollLM[-qW].Last[VecList2],
   vAR - vSR == 8.5*10^(-6) qW*Log[12000/(4.6*10^(-5) qW)]
   };

Res = NSolve[
   Gls, {vAR, phiAR, FQAR, MbAR, vSR, phiSR, FQSR, MbSR, qW}][[1]]
AppendTo[VecList1, {vAR, phiAR, FQAR, MbAR, 1} /. Res];
AppendTo[VecList2, {vSR, phiSR, FQSR, MbSR, 1} /. Res];
```

Comment: Can you produce a _minimal_ representative example? See http://sscce.org/ for guidance.

Comment: Have you tried to use the options for `NSolve`? Check the documentation.

Comment: Could you please describe exactly what is "the trouble" you are having? We appreciate the code, but first we want to know what is wrong.

Comment: Okay, now I can say that I can't use NSolve in that case, because I still have a lot of symblos that aren't solved. So this Problem is more of how can I simplify my equations so I can work with Solve or is their any kind of Mathematical way to solve this Problem?